# How to tell Drupal to use tpl file from my module?

Tags: 7, theming

I have a custom module and placed comment.tpl.php here:

**/sites/all/modules/mymodule/comment.tpl.php**

But Drupal is not looking for that file in my custom module directory. How can i make it work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use hook_theme:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function MY_MODULE_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {

  if($type != 'module') {
    return [];
  }

  // If you want to put your templates in a templates directory
  // in your module directory add .'/templates' to the end.
  $module_path = drupal_get_path('module', 'MY_MODULE');

  return [
    'comment' => [
      'template' => 'comment',
      'path'     => $module_path,
    ],
    'other_template' => [
      'template' => 'comment',
      'path'    => '/my/custom/path/here',
    ],
  ];
}
```

This has set up our custom theme, then when you want to use it you can:

```
$tpl_data = [
  'param1' => $foo,
  'param2' => $bar,
];

return theme('comment', $tpl_data);
```

Now $param1 and $param2 will be available in your template file too.

If you don't need any custom data in your template then $tpl_data can be omitted.

Happy days.

Comment: It worked! Thanks. If i want to use templates from a page,node i just have to change comment on page/node, right?

Comment: If you want to use another template file you can just add another line in your hook_theme function and supply the path to it (answer updated)

Comment: I mean what if i want to use node.tpl.php in my module directory, sorry for such a silly questions :), oh i see now, So it would be 'node' => array('template' => 'node', $path) right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using hook_theme() as described on [api.drupal.org](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_theme/7). It allows you to register your module's theme implementation.

Comment: Can you throw an example please?